# In a directx application, find z (terrain) with known location

Tags: c++, directx, textures, terrain

My english knowlage is not good enought to tell my problems. and i am using stackoverflow second time.

i am hooking a directx application, i just can wrote something to screen and get input from screen and other things.

This game has a terrain, and a lot of players. I can directly edit the player location (x, z, y). But when i edit x and z coordinate, the player is flying :) because i don't know how to calculate the y coordinate (terrain height), i can't calculate it.

Player coordinate is 700, 5.41, 600

when game edit it to 800 and 700, game makes y to 6.50

when i edit it to 800 and 700, the y coordinate still 5.41

6.50 is coordinate, height of terrain of (800, 700), 5.41 is 700,600 terrain height.

Is there a any way to get height of the terrain for speficed coordinate?

Thank you much more.

Comment: _You_ created the terrain somehow, so you tell us!

Comment: i am just hooking this program with dll... I don't know how to create terrain.

Comment: @user439857: Without knowing anything about the terrain, I can't tell you how to know anything about the terrain...

Comment: is there a handle of terrain? if yes, i can get the handle. Which fuctions return the height?

Comment: terrain->GetYValue(x, z)? Seriously, how do you expect anyone to answer this question?

Comment: Sorry, patrik. I was think the solution must be eays. I didn't created and used terrain object. So i don't know, i need to which function returns terrain data, if CreateTexture returns that i can hook the function and get return value then i can use it. I just need an example how to create and use terrain. I am pro. in reserve engineering, i can get which function edits that but that function do something too. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Terrain is specific to the library you are using which you haven't so much as mentioned the name of there is no way to even fathom a guess based on the lack of information provided ... "I am pro in reserve engineering" I'm going to use that quote if you don't mind ;)

Comment: you're right but i am really a starter in directx

Comment: since my app. works good without that, i am gonna forget that.
http://img10.imageshack.us/i/burako.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on Knight OnLine. its a wrapper to CN3Terrain::GetHeight(float x, float z).

```
float getY(float x, float z) {
__asm {
    PUSH 0
    PUSH z
    PUSH x
    MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[0x0C26C20]
    MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+1Ch]
    MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]
    CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+34h]
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it.
Thanks to everyone.

The game is using N3Terrain :)

```
float CN3Terrain::GetHeight(float x, float z)
```

{
    int ix, iz;
    ix = ((int)x) / TILE_SIZE;
    iz = ((int)z) / TILE_SIZE;

```
if(ix<0 || ix>(m_ti_MapSize-2)) return -FLT_MAX;
if(iz<0 || iz>(m_ti_MapSize-2)) return -FLT_MAX;

float dX, dZ;
dX = (x - (ix*TILE_SIZE)) / TILE_SIZE;
dZ = (z - (iz*TILE_SIZE)) / TILE_SIZE;

float y;
float h1, h2, h3, h12, h13;

if((ix+iz)%2==0)    //»ç°¢ÇüÀÌ / ¸ð¾ç.. 
{
    h1 = m_pMapData[ix*m_ti_MapSize + iz].fHeight;
    h3 = m_pMapData[(ix+1)*m_ti_MapSize + (iz+1)].fHeight;
    if (dZ > dX)    //À­ÂÊ »ï°¢Çü..
    {
        h2 = m_pMapData[ix*m_ti_MapSize + (iz+1)].fHeight;

        h12 = h1 + (h2-h1) * dZ;    // h1°ú h2»çÀÌÀÇ ³ôÀÌ°ª
        h13 = h1 + (h3-h1) * dZ;    // h1°ú h3»çÀÌÀÇ ³ôÀÌ°ª

        y = h12 + ((h13-h12) * (dX/dZ));    // Ã£°íÀÚ ÇÏ´Â ³ôÀÌ°ª
        return y;
    }
    else    //¾Æ·¡ÂÊ »ï°¢Çü..
    {
        if(dX==0.0f) return h1;

        h2 = m_pMapData[(ix+1)*m_ti_MapSize + iz].fHeight;

        h12 = h1 + (h2-h1) * dX;    // h1°ú h2»çÀÌÀÇ ³ôÀÌ°ª
        h13 = h1 + (h3-h1) * dX;    // h1°ú h3»çÀÌÀÇ ³ôÀÌ°ª

        y = h12 + ((h13-h12) * (dZ/dX));    // Ã£°íÀÚ ÇÏ´Â ³ôÀÌ°ª
        return y;
    }
}

else if ((ix+iz)%2==1)  //»ç°¢ÇüÀÌ ¿ª½½·¹½¬ ¸ð¾ç..
{
    h1 = m_pMapData[(ix+1)*m_ti_MapSize + iz].fHeight;
    h3 = m_pMapData[ix*m_ti_MapSize + (iz+1)].fHeight;

    if ((dX+dZ) > 1.0f) //À­ÂÊ »ï°¢Çü..
    {
        if(dZ==0.0f) return h1;
        h2 = m_pMapData[(ix+1)*m_ti_MapSize + (iz+1)].fHeight;

        h12 = h1 + (h2-h1) * dZ;
        h13 = h1 + (h3-h1) * dZ;

        y = h12 + ((h13-h12) * ((1.0f-dX)/dZ));
        return y;
    }
    else    //¾Æ·¡ÂÊ »ï°¢Çü..
    {
        if(dX==1.0f) return h1;
        h2 = m_pMapData[ix*m_ti_MapSize + iz].fHeight;

        h12 = h2+(h1-h2)*dX;    // h1°ú h2»çÀÌÀÇ ³ôÀÌ°ª
        h13 = h3+(h1-h3)*dX;    // h1°ú h3»çÀÌÀÇ ³ôÀÌ°ª

        y = h12 + ((h13-h12) * (dZ/(1.0f-dX)));
        return y;
    }
}

return -FLT_MAX;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One engine I used allowed you to cast rays and determine their intersection with objects. I found the "ground" by casting a ray from above aimed down and found the intersection with the terrain.

Comment: i really can't understant because of my english knowlage :(
anyway, thank you